# How to link text fields to functions

Tags: swift

I have to create an app, with a label, a text box and a button, that will take the text that the user inputs and test if it is a palindrome and true a yes or no. It requires that I write the palindrome function in another file and call it when the button is press. The return from the function will also have to be displayed in the label field.

I have written and tested out the function but I don't know how connect it with the 3 objects on my app. They didn't teach how to do this yet in the course and googling the terms "linking text field to function in swift" only confused me more.

How should I go about learning how to do this? What terms should I search for to learn about this? I also included my palindrome funciton as reference.

```
func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool{
    let word2 = word
    let reversedWord = String(word.reversed())
    if word2 == reversedWord {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }


}
```

isPalindrome(word: "racecar")

Comment: Have you built this with a storyboard, or created the UI objects in code? The difference is attaching an event to the code, or linking an `@IBAction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you know how to connect elements from storyboard to your view controller.

Link your textfield to your ViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
```

then your button.

```
let text = textfield.text
@IBAction func checkBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    isPalindrome(word: text!)
}




func isPalindrome(word: String) -> Bool{
    let word2 = word
    let reversedWord = String(word.reversed())
    if word2 == reversedWord {
        print("Is Palindrome")
        return true
    } else {
        print("Isn't Palindrome")
        return false
    }


}
```

Also I don't think that you need to return something, except you want to use it.

for example:

```
if isPalindrome(word: text!){
  //do something

} else{
//do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I learned about how to link the elements, but not how to actually put text in the labels.

Comment: If my answer is correct pls vote up and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboard, check how the `@IBAction` and `IBOutlet` works. its a visual way to link objects from storyboard into your code. If you created these label, textfield, button from code then checkout the `addTarget` method of `UIButton` for how to listen for click events.